# Simulate type deduction on return type using temp. proxy with conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functional-programming

I have this Haskell-style `map` higher-order function which already uses template type deduction for a clean syntax on the caller side, except for the result type:

```
template<class ResultingContainer, class R, class Fn>
ResultingContainer map(const R &range, const Fn &f) {
    ResultingContainer result;
    using value_type = decltype(*std::begin(range));
    for_each(range, [&](const value_type &v){
        result.push_back(f(v));
    });
    return result;
}
```

<sub>(I prefer `decltype(*std::begin(range))` over `R::value_type` or some iterator traits, because I use containers which don't provide such an interface: Qt containers.)</sub>

Using this function is simple but not as simple as I want it to be, you all know what I mean:

```
std::vector<int> result = map<std::vector<int>>(otherVector, someFunction);
```

Of course, I want it to be:

```
std::vector<int> result = map(otherVector, someFunction);
```

If I designed the API in the following way, type deduction would work perfectly. But I don't want it to be like this, as this is C++ standard library style (except the difference between iterator pair / range), but I want it to be "Haskell-style":

```
std::vector<int> result;
map(otherVector, result, someFunction);
```

Given the fact that `otherVector` doesn't necessarily be of the same type as the result (for example, they could be strings and I want their length, so `someFunction` returns the length of a given string), I can't express the type `ResultingContainer` only using the already known types (in particular, the input's value type).

If I (and I don't want to) stick to one single type of container, I could express it. But there is one hope left: The compiler already knows what the result should be, unless `auto` is used for the return type. (And it will be confusing when there are multiple possibilities on the result type, e.g. when used as an argument to an overloaded function).

So I thought about a *proxy container*, which is the default `ResultingContainer` (but can be overwritten if the user needs to, that's not my problem). However, with my current knowledge I could only implement some `ProxyContainer<T>` (with `T` being the result type of `f`, the predicate used in `map`), which *temporarily holds all result items*. This sounds like unnecessary overhead. However, an implementation could look like:

```
template<typename T>
class ProxyContainer : public std::vector<T> {
    template<typename FinalContainer>
    operator FinalContainer() const {
        FinalContainer result;
        for (auto x : *this)
            result.push_back(x);
        return result;
    }
};
```

But this just doesn't feel right.

Can you come up with a better solution?

Comment: `stuff | boost::adaptors::transformed(f)`? And then either use just that lazy adapted range and pass it along, or if you really need it as a concrete container, create one from its iterator: `auto r = /*see above*/; cont c(r.begin(), r.end());`

Comment: I don't want to change the syntax on the caller side. Except making the template parameter optional. So I want to return an adaptor within my function. Is this possible using boost adaptors?

Comment: Thanks Xeo, the "lazy" thing is exactly what I needed. I came up with a custom solution, see my answer. However, there is still one drawback: When using auto for a temporary result, and using the result multiple times elsewhere, it will be evaluated multiple times. The user should be aware of that and avoid auto in this case. Or can I make it possible to allow my class only as temporary values?

Comment: `decltype(*std::begin(range))` isn't quite right, as it doesn't support ADL-based lookup for `begin`.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks for this hint. Does the new range-based for loop syntax use ADL-based lookup for `begin`? I thought it always uses `std::begin` (and `end` respectively)...

Comment: Yes it does.  As an example: `namespace toy { struct foo { int arr[5]; }; int* begin( foo& f ) { return std::begin( f.arr ); } int* end( foo& f ) { return std::end( f.arr ); } } typedef toy::foo bar;` names an object `bar` with an ADL-accessible `begin` and `end` that ranged-based `for` will find, but your code won't.

Comment: @Yakk Well, then thanks again, I'll made these changes to be consistent. However, I can't just write `begin(range)`, I have to write `using std::begin` to do so. But this is a header, and `using` in headers is evil. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic lazy adaptor implementation, together with some `container_traits` allowing you to return your data into a `std::set` or the like.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

// Standard metaprogramming boilerplate:
template<std::size_t...>
struct seq {};
template<std::size_t max, std::size_t... s>
struct make_seq:make_seq<max-1, max-1, s...> {};
template<std::size_t... s>
struct make_seq<0, s...> {
  typedef seq<s...> type;
};
// helper to make creating a sequence from 0,...,max-1 take less typing:
template<std::size_t max>
using MakeSeq = typename make_seq<max>::type;

// takes a sequence of indexes, a tuple, a Result type, and a Functor, and calls the Functor passing
// in the Result type with the fowarded args in the tuple, as indicated by the sequence of indexes:
template<typename Result, template<typename Result>class Functor, typename... Args, std::size_t... s>
Result apply( seq<s...>, std::tuple<Args...>& args ) {
  return Functor<Result>()(std::forward<Args>(std::get<s>(args))...);
}

// and here it is, a generic lazy evaluator:
template<template<typename Result>class Functor, typename... Args>
struct LazyEvaluation {
  std::tuple<Args...> stored_args;
  LazyEvaluation( Args... args ):stored_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {};
  template<typename R>
  operator R() {
    return apply<R, Functor>( MakeSeq<sizeof...(Args)>(), stored_args );
  }
};

// The start of some container traits templates:
template<typename T, typename=void>
struct const_iterator_type:std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct const_iterator_type<T, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same< typename T::const_iterator, typename T::const_iterator >::value
>::type>:std::true_type {
   typedef typename T::const_iterator const_iterator;
};
template<typename T, size_t n>
struct const_iterator_type< T[n] >:std::true_type {
   typedef T const* const_iterator;
};


template<typename T,typename=void>
struct has_push_back:std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_push_back<T, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<
     decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(*std::declval<typename const_iterator_type<T>::const_iterator>())),
     decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(*std::declval<typename const_iterator_type<T>::const_iterator>()))
  >::value
>::type>:std::true_type{};
template<typename T,typename=void>
struct has_insert:std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct has_insert<T, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<
     decltype(std::declval<T>().insert(*std::declval<typename const_iterator_type<T>::const_iterator>())),
     decltype(std::declval<T>().insert(*std::declval<typename const_iterator_type<T>::const_iterator>()))
  >::value
>::type>:std::true_type {};

template<typename Container, typename=void>
struct container_traits;

template<typename Container>
struct container_traits<Container, typename std::enable_if<has_push_back<Container>::value>::type> {
   template<typename V>
   static void add_to_container( Container& c, V&& v ) {
     c.push_back( std::forward<V>(v) );
   }
};
template<typename Container>
struct container_traits<Container, typename std::enable_if<!has_push_back<Container>::value && has_insert<Container>::value>::type> {
   template<typename V>
   static void add_to_container( Container& c, V&& v ) {
     c.insert( std::forward<V>(v) );
   }
};

// supporting emplace_back and emplace is harder, but probably worth it.
// the trick with both of them is that you only know if they exist or are valid
// after you try to call add_to_container with the arguments!  So instead of
// "does it exist", you end up with "can we call emplace_back with these arguments".
// This requires a bit of slight of hand in the template code, as we want to fall back
// on insert and push_back if emplace_back doesn't exist.

// Another improvement to the above might be to have the const_iterator traits class
// fall back on a decltype( std::begin(std::declval<C const>()) ) -- or even better,
// do full ADL with a private namespace and a using std::begin.

// your code, basically verbatim, but uses container_traits to figure out
// how to add an element to the container:
template<class ResultingContainer, class Range, class Fn>
ResultingContainer map_now(const Range &range, const Fn &f) {
  ResultingContainer result;
  using value_type = decltype(*std::begin(range));
  for_each(std::begin(range), std::end(range), [&](const value_type &v){
    container_traits<ResultingContainer>::add_to_container(result, f(v));
  });
  return result;
}

// could make this easier if I could pass in a pointer-to-template-function
// or the equivalent directly.  Know the syntax by any chance?
template<typename Range, typename Fn>
struct map_lazy_helper {
  template<typename ResultingContainer>
  struct Func {
    ResultingContainer operator()(const Range &range, const Fn &f) const {
      return map_now<ResultingContainer>( range, f );
    }
  };
};

// Map lazy is mostly repeating type information:
template<typename Range, typename Fn>
LazyEvaluation<map_lazy_helper<Range, Fn>::template Func, Range, Fn>
map_lazy(Range&&range, Fn&&f) {
  return {std::forward<Range>(range), std::forward<Fn>(f)};
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> tester {3,2,1};

   std::vector<double> vd = map_lazy( tester, [](int x) { return x*0.5; } );
   std::set<double> sd = map_lazy( tester, [](int x) { return x*0.5; } );
   std::vector<int> vs = map_lazy( tester, [](int x) { return x*2; } );
   for(auto&& x:vd)
     std::cout << x << "\n";
   for(auto&& x:sd)
     std::cout << x << "\n";
   for(auto&& x:vs)
     std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

which works as well as you might like.  :)

Amusingly, while this answer is huge, 40% of it is a generic "add to container" code that handles `set`, 10% is metaprogramming boilerplate, 30% is a generic `LazyEvaluation`, 10% is test code, and only 10% is the code required to actually write `map_lazy`.

And now that I think about it, what you want is a generic "insert stuff into container" iterator, so you can support writing to a `std::array` of sufficient size, a `std::set`, a `std::vector` or a homebrew container.  It should probe for `back_insert_iterator`, failing that `insert_iterator( C.end() )`, with specializations for fixed sized containers like `std::array` (which have a size even when empty!).  That would make `container_traits` even more complex, and it already takes up about half of this post!

Finally, here is an ADL-enabled "does the container support begin":

```
namespace aux_adl {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_begin( C&& c )->decltype( begin(std::forward<C>(c)) );
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_end( C&& c )->decltype( end(std::forward<C>(c)) );
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_cbegin( C const& c )->decltype( begin(c) );
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_cend( C const& c )->decltype( end(c) );
}
template<typename C, typename=void>
struct container_iterator {}
template<typename C>
struct container_iterator<C, std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<
    decltype( adl_aux::adl_begin(std::declval<C>()),
    decltype( adl_aux::adl_end(std::declval<C>())
  >::value
>::type> {
  typedef adl_aux::adl_begin(std::declval<C>()) iterator;
};
template<typename C>
struct container_const_iterator<C, std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<
    decltype( adl_aux::adl_cbegin(std::declval<C>()),
    decltype( adl_aux::adl_cend(std::declval<C>())
  >::value
>::type> {
  typedef adl_aux::adl_cbegin(std::declval<C>()) const_iterator;
};
```

Note that the `adl_end` type functions only do proper ADL type lookup, they cannot actually be called.

And yes, it is a hack.  And apparently someone is bugging the C++ committee to allow `using` declarations inside `decltype` to fix up this hack a tad.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this long answer. I'll add it piece by piece to my code base. Especially, I like the container traits, which I might copy 1:1. Supporting containers without `push_back` has been a todo until now. ;) Maybe I'll add code to handle Qt's associative containers like QMap and QHash, which use the syntax [`c.insert(key,value)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html#insert) (so a pair needs to be split before forwarded). But this would be complicated anyway, since their iterator doesn't use pairs at all... On the other side, I won't need assoc containers for a while, I guess.

Comment: @leemes as another aside, you might want to think about the generator pattern -- ie, have your `map` function return a generator, which can be assigned to a Container or turned into a forward iteration Range (where the elements are produced on request).  This takes a bit more effort, but I like the effects of this pattern in python.  As a bonus, when assigning to fixed sized containers (like `std::array`) you won't waste effort transforming elements, and when you are a Range don't have to precompute your values and store them.  `template<typename Emplacer> bool Generate( Emplacer&& e )`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using a "lazy adapter" as Xeo suggested. But instead of using the Boost one, I wrote a very simple one:

```
template<class R, class Fn>
class MapAdaptor
{
    const R &range;
    const Fn &f;

public:
    MapAdaptor(const R &range, const Fn &f) :
        range(range), f(f)
    {
    }

    template<class ResultingContainer>
    operator ResultingContainer() const {
        ResultingContainer result;
        for(const auto &v : range)
            result.push_back(f(v));
        return result;
    }
};
```

Then, the actual `map` function becomes the following:

```
template<class R, class Fn>
MapAdaptor<R,Fn> map(const R &range, const Fn &f) {
    return MapAdaptor<R,Fn>(range, f);
}
```

I didn't make the adaptor a range itself yet, but I'll add this functionality, in order to be able to chain / nest operations.

Comment: Beware of rvalues, to which references-to-const will bind. You might want to consider disabling rvalues through an overload, although this would hinder the nesting/chaining ability.